# Javascript nested prototype method scope

Tags: javascript, scope, prototype

Here is the sample code that I am trying to execute.

```
var Game = function(){
  this.state = 'yeah';
}

Game.prototype.call = function(){
  document.writeln(this.state);
  Game.prototype.say();
}

Game.prototype.say = function(){
  document.writeln(this.state);
}

game = new Game();
game.call();
```

The result is `yeah undefined` which means that the `call()` is working properly while the `say()` isn't. What can I do for `say()` function to be able to get this.state from Game object?

Comment: I would not recommend defining a method `.call()`.  While it technically may work in some circumstances, it could really confuse people with `Function.call()` which every function has already.

Comment: You shouldn't be using [`writeln`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20001113/html.html#ID-35318390) as if the document is closed (e.g. after the load event has been dispatched), it will first call [`document.open`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-72161170) which will clear the document of existing content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Game.prototype.call = function(){
  document.writeln(this.state);
  this.say();
}
```

prototype is used in for defining the function - not calling it

Answer (score 0):

never, please never override native methods (like `call` in this case)..

also something like this works too

```
Game.prototype.call = function(){
  document.writeln(this.state);
  Game.prototype.say.apply(this);
}
```

Comment: `call` is not a native function on objects, it exists on `Function.prototype`, but doesn't get hidden in this case. I agree that you should avoid naming functions `call`, but it's not *that* big of a deal.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want is:

```
Game.prototype.call = function(){
  document.writeln(this.state);
  this.say();
}
```

However this version will call whatever function is set at `this.say`, which might be overridden if the object is inherited:

```
var MyGame = function () {};
MyGame.prototype = new Game();
MyGame.prototype.say = function () {
    document.writeln('something else');
};
var m = new MyGame();
m.call(); //'something else'
```

If you want to use the original reference to `Game.prototype.say` (without inheritance), then you'll need to call the function in the context of the object:

```
Game.prototype.call = function(){
  document.writeln(this.state);
  Game.prototype.say.call(this);
}
var m = new MyGame();
m.call(); //'yeah'
```

Answer (score 0):

TGH has given you a solution but not explained it. Your problem is here:

```
> Game.prototype.say();
```

You are calling `say` as a method of `Game.prototype`, so in the function:

```
> Game.prototype.say = function(){
>   document.writeln(this.state); 
> }
```

`this` is a reference to the prototype object, not the instance. You want to call the function as:

```
 this.say();
```

so that it's called as a method of the instance, thereby setting `this` within `say` to the instance.